# PageSpeed Insights - Serves images with low resolution - WPML Language Flag Images

Tags: pagespeed-insights, wpml

I have noted that if I insert my WPML Language switcher into my header using "do_action('wpml_add_language_selector');", then Pagespeed Insights records an issue with the language flags image sizes under the Best Practices section of the Pagespeed Insights report.

If I remove "do_action('wpml_add_language_selector');" and insert the Language switcher by adding a language switcher in the WordPress dashboard > WPML > Languages > Menu Language switcher, and run another test on Pagespeed Insights, then the problem with the language flag image sizes is no longer recorded under the Best Practices section.

Why is this?
Are there any options or parameters within the wpml_add_language_selector function which can be used to configure it better in order to resolve the issue from being recorded in my Pagespeed Insights report?

I am expecting that the Pagespeed Insights report will not record that the language switcher flag images are problem with regard to size.

I have tried css to set the image dimensions but this just adjusts the requirement on the report instead of resolving the issue.